# Array muito grande - Android

Tags: java, android

Quais **problemas** eu poderia enfrentar na manipulação de **arrays** muitos grandes?

Quando digo **arrays** me refiro a pelo menos **25**, cada um contendo +de **1000** index.

- **Desempenho**:

O desempenho do meu aplicativo seria afetado? Digo por exemplo, na hora de carregar a activity ou mudar um dado de um index.

- **Forma correta**:

Nesse caso seria mais recomendado o uso de um **Arraylist<>**? Se sim, porque?

Comment: 25 arrays ? Isso certamente é algo errado na conceção. Não deveria antes ser um array de objetos tendo cada um deles 25 campos ? Pessoalmente não vejo muitos motivos para necessitar de 25 arrays separados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesta ordem de grandeza (1000), nem precisa se preocupar. Se fosse um milhão de elementos... mas não faça otimizações prematuras. Teste, faça profile e depois tire suas conclusões.

A questão do container depende do que você vai fazer com os dados, não o desempenho puro. Você vai acessar os dados de forma aleatória (pelo índice) ou sequencial? A matriz terá de mudar de tamanho? Cada container atende a uma demanda diferente.

Comment: Tipo, 1k é quase o minimo, podem chegar até 20k cada um, na vdd

Comment: Certo, mas ainda não preocupa. Esses dias fiz uma rotina de tratamento de imagem em Java puro, executa diversos cálculos sobre uma matriz de 1600x1200x3 (~6M elementos) e a velocidade surpreendeu. Para você ter uma ideia, ganhou do iOS/Swift em modo debug...